# Query from Bigquery using local command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to query from BigQuery using PowerShell. I've initialised gcloud init and logged in to my account.
The request was this:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT customer_id FROM `demo1.customers1`'
```

Resulting with this error:

```
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job
'PROJECT-ID:bqjob': Access Denied:
BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.
```

This worked when I run it in cloud shell.

I've created a service account before and a key for the project. I tried to run this command and doesn't solve it:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT@DOMAIN.COM --key-file=D:/folder/key.json --project=MYPROJECT_ID
```

Comment: Does the service account has BigQuery permission?

Comment: Yes. I set it as the owner

Comment: Could you please try `bq ls`.  Just ensure that this account able to access BigQuery.

Comment: Sure. It shows the datasetId

Comment: Does try query with full resource (`project.dataset.table`) e.g `bq query 'SELECT * FROM project.dataset.table`

Comment: Tried it. Same problem occurs

Comment: Can you try this command `“gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access”`? Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: Thanks! It works. I asked this on another forum too and notice this occurs because I tried to query from a table that was uploaded using sheets and it requires drive authentication. I tried the query using a different dataset and worked just fine. Appreciate it the response!

Comment: Hi @hyvel, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: Sure! Sorry, forgot to upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service account should have the OAuth scope for [Drive](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#Google_Drive_permissions) to access drive, below command can be used to authenticate with Drive.

```
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
```